# creating a cypress command that will get button and add infinite cypress action based on user input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress, cypress-custom-commands

I want to create a cypress custom command that based on user arguments will add cypress action and chain them together

Now I have something like this:

```
Cypress.Commands.add(
  'selectButton',
  (text: string, ...actionType: ButtonActionTypes[]) => {
    let cyActions = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < actionType.length; i++) {
      const cyAction = actionType[i];
      const getActionType = getAction(text, actionType);

      if (getActionType !== null) {
        cyActions += `${getActionType}`;
      } else {
        cyActions += cyAction;
      }

      `${cy.get('button')}.${cyActions}`;
    }
  }
);

function getAction(text, action) {
  switch (action) {
    case 'click':
      'click()';
      break;
    case 'visible':
      'should("be.visible")';
      break;
    case 'disabled':
      'should("be.disabled")';
      break;
    case 'blur':
      'blur()';
      break;
    case 'contains':
      `contains(${text})`;
      break;
  }
}
```

But this is not working as i want. Although it is selecting buttons, but if i want to create this:
`cy.selectButton('Send').should('be.visible').should('be.disabled');`
based on that
`cy.selectButton('Send', 'visible', 'disabled', 'click');`
I am getting all buttons that i have on my site

Answer (score 2):

You could probably handle assertions since the syntax underlying `.should('be.visible')` is `expect(subject).to.be.visible` and the `.to`, `.be`, `.visible` are just properties of the `expect(subject)` wrapper of your assertion subject.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add(
  'selectButton',
  (text: string, ...actionTypes: ButtonActionTypes[]) => {
    let cyActions = '';

    cy.get(text).then($el => {

      const expectWrapper = expect($el)  // wraps subject for chain of assertions

      [...actionTypes].forEach(actionType => {
        expectWrapper[actionType]
      })      
  }
)
```

I don't know about the commands, it's a little more difficult to add those dynamically - might be impossible, since Cypress likes to set up the command queue before running it.